# How to stop third-party Erlang applications

Tags: erlang

I am in the process of writing my first erlang application and I don't understand yet some parts of the erlang ecosystem and how things should be done in it. For example if my app depends on some other apps what is the way to start **and stop** them at once ? Actually, I've figured out how to start, just put `application:start/1` calls in the `start/2` function of the application module:

```
-module(myapp).
-behaviour(application).

-export([start/0, start/2, stop/1]).

start(_Type, _StartArgs) ->
    ok = application:start(ssl),
    ok = application:start(inets),
    ok = application:start(log4erl),
    myapp_sup:start_link().

stop(_State) ->
    ok.
```

But when I tried to put corresponding `application:stop/1` calls into the `myapp:stop/1` function and called from the erlang shell `application:stop(myapp)` the later just stopped responding to any command.

Comment: Just stop the other apps in your `stop` function. As Roberto said, your own app is stoped by platform.

Comment: ... and hope no other running applications relied on the stopped ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading from the official doc:

> stop/1 is called **after** the application
>   has been stopped and should do any
>   necessary cleaning up. Note that the
>   actual stopping of the application,
>   that is the shutdown of the
>   supervision tree, is handled
>   automatically as described in [Starting
>   and Stopping Applications](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html#stopping).

More information [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html) and [there](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html).

Usually, when I have some dependent applications, I use a .app resource file, where I list all applications that need to be started (or loaded) by my application to work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest checking out erlware.org and using the tools sinan and faxien for your Erlang development. If you stick to strict OTP compliance for your apps and releases it not only makes development easier and less error prone but it makes sharing your apps much much easier. The upcoming book http://www.manning.com/logan/ answers much more, you can read an early copy in pdf form.

Putting starts and stops "randomly" in your modules is a bad idea.

Comment: "sinan" and "faxien" don't appear to exist any more. Google takes me to dead GitHub pages.

Answer (score 0):

You already got some good suggestions. Let me just add an explanation of the problem you're seeing: your `stop` callback function is called synchronously by the application controller, i.e., the application controller will not do anything else until your function returns. But you ask the application controller to stop some other applications—and the two processes are in a deadlock, waiting for each other.